# Suppport/disable MathJax in newsletter

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, newsletter

The weekly newsletter is hard to read because the the math questions are in MathJax code. The code is not transformed into readable format. It's a bunch of dollar signs and slashes, ...etc. No one is going to take the time to decipher it. So... my **suggestion**: make the newsletter problems readable as plain old type, or find some way to have the MathJax code interpreted and presented as its intent was.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that MathJax requires JavaScript to render, however emails don't allow you to execute JavaScript.

A solution would be to provide a "Open in browser" link that opens a webpage for the email. The webpage can execute JavaScript and hence render MathJax.

If the Math StackExchange community doesn't work on this, I'll create a web extension to accomplish this. Stay tuned.